# SQL Questions Regarding Select Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What percentage of third-party registered voters actually voted? What percentage of non-3rd-party registered voters actually voted?

```
Select count(*)
From Vote V, Voter B, Person P
Where V.Person_ID = B.Person_ID AND B.Register ‘1’ AND (P.Party IN ( ‘Dem’ , ‘Rep’ );
```

This includes the count of how many people that is within the third national party and is registered that voted but I don't understand how would I be able to divide that with the total number of votes.

```
CREATE TABLE Vote(
  Vote_ID int,
  Person_ID int,            //V.Person_ID, C.Person_ID
  Title varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(Vote_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Person(
  Person_ID int,
  First_Name varchar (50),
  Mid_Name varchar(50),
  Last_Name varchar(50),
  Street varchar(45),
  Zipcode int,
  Party varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Voter(
  Person_ID int,
  Registered int,
  PRIMARY KEY(Person_ID)
);
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: non-3rd-party = Person.Party  is null , 3rd-party = Person.Party  is  notnull?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  SQL Server and MySQL are 2 completely different products.

Comment: Also, use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Your data needs a bit more explanation because people can vote more than once.  Presumably, you want someone who has *ever* voted.

The structure of the question suggests a query like this:

```
select (case when party in ('Dem', 'Rep') 
               then 'DemRep' else '3rdParty'
         end),
       count(v.person_id) * 1.0 / count(*)
from person p left join
     (select distinct v.person_id
      from vote v
     ) v 
     on v.person_id = p.person_id
where exists (select 1
              from voter vr
              where vr.register = 1 and vr.personid = v.person_id
             )
group by (case when party in ('Dem', 'Rep') 
               then 'DemRep' else '3rdParty'
          end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the percentage of your registered voters based on party. Use `sum()` to get the values based on `case` statement criteria. then divided by total `count()`

```
select sum(case when b.Registered = 1 and p.Party in ('Dem', 'Rep') then 1 else 0 end)/count(1) * 100 as ThirdParty
    , sum(case when b.Registered = 1 and p.Party not in ('Dem', 'Rep') then 1 else 0 end)/count(1) * 100 as NonThirdParty
from Vote v
inner join Voter b on b.Person_ID = v.Person_ID
inner join Person p on p.Person_ID = v.Person_ID
```